# How do I Skip the first row in an sqldatareader

Tags: c#

I am retrieving 10 rown from my database but I want to skip the first one. Reason being that the first item in my table is already displayed within the main div on my page. Now I want to list all the other remaining records underneath it. How do I accomplish this?

My code works ok and I can display all records from the reader. All I need now is how to skip the first one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just read the first one, then continue with the others:

```
myReader.Read();

while(myReader.Read())
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you like to use Linq, here's a trick to make it work with DataReaders, using a simple extension method :

```
public static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> AsEnumerable(this IDataReader reader)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        yield return reader;
    }
}
```

You can then use the Linq `Skip` method :

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteRead())
{
    foreach(var row in reader.AsEnumerable.Skip(1))
    {
        // whatever you do with the data...
    }
}
```

Comment: Six years later, you've taught me an invaluable lesson. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `reader.Read()` one extra time to start with, to advance to the next record. Then treat the reader as normal. You may want to still check the value of `reader.Read()` from that first call - if it returns `false` then there wasn't even the first record you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help thinking that there's got to be something else "wrong" when you require skipping the first row in your DataReader like:

- Maybe your SQL query, sproc or whatever should exclude the first row instead?
- Why do you already have your first row? Maybe you could get all the rows at the same time?

Your question implies a lack of coding experience - either in general or with regards to DataReader or something. Maybe you could get even more help if you explained why you need to skip the first row?